# How to solve: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampledb

Tags: java, mysql

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampledb
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at MySQLConnectExample2.main(MySQLConnectExample2.java:21)
```

I'm getting this error and this is my java code

```
String url1 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampledb";
String user = "root";
String password = "14701";

conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url1, user, password);
if (conn1 != null) {
    System.out.println("Connected to the database test1");
}
```

every time i'm executing

```
java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar;. MySQLConnectExample
```

on cmd the followin error is occurring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the class driver before getting a connection:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html) is an example.

and the working code:

```
Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/sampledb?" + "user=root&password=14701");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `MySQLConnectExample2.java:9: error: unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                     ^
MySQLConnectExample2.java:9: error: unreported exception InstantiationException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                                                          ^
2 errors`

Comment: @Ajax Put a try catch block around Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()

Comment: It's under try block

Comment: Show me your entire source code in your question and the stacktrace

Comment: `import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class MySQLConnectExample2{
 public static void main(String args[]){
  try {
   Connection conn = null;
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/sampledb?" +"user=root&password=14701");
  } catch (SQLException ex) {
   System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
   System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
   System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
  }
 }
}`

Comment: `MySQLConnectExample2.java:8: error: unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                                     ^
MySQLConnectExample2.java:8: error: unreported exception InstantiationException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                                                                          ^
2 errors`

Comment: @Ajax Replace SQLException with  Exception because it does not compile

Comment: @Ajax Or, even better add this block to try:  catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: @Ajax I suggest you to use an IDE.

Comment: `MySQLConnectExample2.java:8: error: unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                                     ^
MySQLConnectExample2.java:8: error: unreported exception InstantiationException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                                                                          ^
2 errors` same error is coming

Comment: I know IDE is an option but I want to do this without using IDE

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the driver/connector in the classpath. Go to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/8.0.html and download the jar file and put in your classpath.

Something like this:

```
java -cp .;mysql-connector-java-xx-xx.jar com.xx.xx.yourApp
```

you also need to load the driver like this:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```